# Android - Using camera intent (ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) shows different orientations

Tags: android, camera, android-orientation

I'm simply trying to open the native camera intent as follows:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(
                                    MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(
                                    MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                    Statics.CAMERA_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

After shooting the video - the android presents it correctly (portrait), but the computer shows it (mp4 file) in wrong orientation - 90 degrees left.
I've also tried to change the EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION to LANDSCAPE and it still didn't work right.

any suggestions what else to do? thanks.

Comment: Hei can you please explain how did you change the orientation to landscape only using extras. My problem is, i open the camera-> record a video in lanscape mode-> change the phone to Portrait-> Stop recording, the recorder doesn't show the done button to select the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent)
```

use ExifInterface

Comment: Just tried it. it doesn't save the orientation value. it return 0 (ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) after shooting in landscape and portrait.